# How to give textbox id in a json url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have the following url.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://reportguru.webdenza.com/vdetect-pro-2/api.php?q={\"svc\":\"auth\",\"params\":{\"username\":\"abcdefgh\",\"password\":\"12345678\"}}");
```

Instead of passing directly username and password I want to pass these through `textbox` in c#.
I tried by giving textboxes but it shows error during parsing.

I am getting the following error.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Path '', line 3, position 1.

Help me please

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried and which is giving error?

Comment: what code you're using to parse?

Comment: var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);